# How to rename the uploaded file to store in a single folder

Tags: php, file

My client needs the file name to be in the same name as it was uploaded. But I need to store all the files in the same folder. How? or what is the best way to handle this so that I could make the client download the file in the same name as he had uploaded.

Comment: why you dont just get  the original file name and then add the date when it was uploaded  so the name will be(exemple)  date-originalfilename.jpg  ,

Comment: when my client downloads I need to give him the exact file name which was uploded even if he has given space in between the files

Comment: so what are you trying to do? do you want to remain it or not? I dont understand the question

Comment: show us your code and then I'll probably understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $randString = md5(time()); //encode the timestamp - returns a 32 chars long string

  $fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; //the original file name

  $splitName = explode(".", $fileName); //split the file name by the dot

  $fileExt = end($splitName); //get the file extension

  $newFileName  = strtolower($randString.'.'.$fileExt); //join file name and ext.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$name = "foto";
$extension = ".png";

$today = date("Y/m/d-H:i:s");
$fullName = $name."_".$today.$fileExtension;
  //where $name was it's actual name
  //$today is todays date and time
  //$file extension would be something like ".png"
```

An example of the value of `$fullName` would be `foto_2001/03/10-17:16:18.png`

Comment: when my client downloads I need to give him the exact file name which was uploded even if he has given space in between the files

Comment: this dosent answer the question mate! the name is not the same .